# What should I do about a not-so-good dungeon master?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

I'm part of a group where the only D.M. Is a really bad dm. He plays with overpowered GMPCs, and he doesn't even roll the checks on tests.

What should I do?

Comment: Hi and welcome, this question is extraordinarily broad. Please clarify what *exactly* is the issue with some examples and details. But please keep in mind, if you just want to vent about your terrible DM, this is the wrong place. If you want actual solutions (sometimes the best choice is to leave though), you'll get those here if you provide a *lot* more details.

Comment: Do you mean he makes his character up? Are you talking about a non player character, or is he also running a character in the dungeon?

Comment: He is not english-proficient, but I get what he is trying to say. He have a DM with a GMPC that overpowers his character and don't play fair. Probably the DM is the only one that had ever read the books, also, and "cheat" the others. Pretty common on non-english countries.

Comment: have you considered GMing yourself?

Comment: @JohnP He said "makes his character totally **OP**", meaning over-powered. I'm more wondering why the DM has a "his character" in the first place. To clarify: user11575, does the DM also run a personal player-character, like the rest of the players do? Or are you talking about just other characters in the world being all overpowered?

Answer (score 5):

The best solution to bad GMs is good GMs both as examples and competition.  If your club only has one GM I would recommend that you take a turn behind the screen.  You may or may not enjoy it in the long run but in my experience the key power of a bad GM is the sense that there is no where else to go.

You could encourage others to take a turn GMing as well.  You could even introduce new games as part of the process.

Answer (score 3):

As [@wax-eagle](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/36641/what-should-i-do-about-a-not-so-good-dungeon-master/36644#comment73128_36641) said, this is a broad question. But, here's what you can do.

1. Talk to the DM: Tell them you don't like what they're doing and see if they can explain why they're doing it. Maybe that character is given carte blanche by the plot. Maybe this is their first time and they don't understand what they're doing. Include the others: If you're the only one having an issue, see #3.
2. Roleplay around it: It sucks, but sometimes your character is given a sucky situation you have to roleplay out of. Take this as an opportunity to overcome a challenging situation.
3. Leave: If you're not having fun, and it seems like everyone else is, then don't play. If you still want to hang out, hang out. Be a spectator, if they'll let you. But don't let this thing become a chore for you.